# Embedding My Laravel Web Application in Another Site

Tags: laravel, web-applications, laravel-8, embed

I have a working laravel web app, which I would like others to be able to include on their own website. [edit] I would only like individuals who have an account with us to be able to do this.[/edit]

I envisage them adding something like this to their page:

```
<script src="https://myappsourceurl.com/js/code.js"></script>
```

and perhaps a custom tag similar to this to position it on the page.

```
<myapp> or <div id="myapp">
</myapp> or </div>
```

I've used [this JSON editor](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor) in the past, and something along these kinds of lines might work [edit] or perhaps more like the way you can [integrate the stripe payments system](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart) would be ideal.[/edit]

I'm fairly new to Laravel, and I don't know how to package it up in the right way to achieve this. I'm also struggling to find the right terms to search I keep coming across ways to embed things in laravel, rather than the other way around.

Any direction would be really useful — even just the correct terminology to search!

Many thanks,

Mike

Comment: It can be done using an iframe

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question with a little more information. Essentially, I need something that is set up per organisation/website, rather than something that can be embedded anywhere.

Comment: You can provide organization/website identification in your URL and let them embed it as iframe.